# Minimum number of tetra elements required, to represent a cube?

Tags: finite-element-method

What is the minimum number of TET elements you need, in order to fully fill a cube(HEX element)?

Comment: Do you have any additional criteria besides fewest elements? If I'm understanding correctly, the answer would be 2, as you can create two tetrahedral elements by splitting a cube in half through two opposite vertices. But that won't necessarily yield good results.

Comment: @Trevor: It doesn't work that way. There is no cutting plane you can appply to a cube to end up with two tetrahedrons.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yep, you're right. Took me a while to figure out what I was missing since I didn't have a cube in front of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 5 tet elements]

**Image 1**: 5 tetrahedral elements can form a cube.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAhgw2Z4T2M) shows how to decompose a cube into five tetrahedra. Not saying it can't be done with less, but I can't figure out how :-)

Comment: "Not saying it can't be done with less:" It's easy to show you need at least 5 tets. A cube has 8 vertices (corners). One tet has 4 vertices. If you build a mesh by adding an element which shares a face with the previously assembled elements, you add at most one more vertex. (In some situations, adding the element might not add any new vertices.) So to get 8 vertices, you need at *least* 5 elements. And the picture shows you can indeed do it with at *most* 5 elements.